# What does "block" do in Mail

Tags: mail.app, macos

In the Mail app, when you right click on a person's email address, one of the options is "block".  But this doesn't stop you from receiving emails from them in the future.  All it seems to do is to decorate future emails with a red circle icon with a line through it.

Is this all that "block"ing an email address does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few more steps to do.

After clicking on BLOCK
you will see

[image: junk]

Click on Preferences (on the right)

or Click on Mail>Preferance

It will open new window where you can decide what to do.

This will not delete the Junk mails you already have, but it will prevent future emails, and delete them (if you chose so) before you see them.

[image: block spam]

Comment: This will still not stop you from receiving the emails, though, it will only prevent Mail from showing them to you. In order to prevent receiving them, you need access to the configuration of the mail server. In fact, in order for Mail to be able to inspect the email and filter, it *has* to receive it first.

Comment: Ugghhh .. that is bad UI design INMHO

Comment: @JörgWMittag I understand that, but marking a sender as blocked, and still showing those emails was weird default behavior.